# Can we say node.js is a web server?

Tags: node.js, webserver, terminology, web-frameworks

I found that I am confusing web framework and web server.

- Apache is a web server.
- Tornado is a web server written in Python.
- Nginx is a web server written in C
- Zend is a web framework in php
- Flask/Bottle is a web framework in Python
- RoR is a web framework written in Ruby
- Express is a web framework written in JS under Node.JS

Can we say that node.js is a web server?

If somehow node.js is kind of a webserver, not webframework (Express does), why do we need to put the whole node.js on top of Nginx server in useful practice?

Comment: Tornado is a web server + a small web framework. :) I think ezpresso is right. Node.js is actually a runtime environment much like Java's JRE. Node.js is being used more and more for non-web applications. Programs you write with Node.js have no web server capability unless you add it. Granted, Node.js has very high level native functions that allow you to easily create a web server with http.CreateServer(...).listen(80); but there is no web server in existence in your program unless you add this. So Node.js itself is not a web server. Rather, you use Node.js to create one.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to put a web server on top of Node.js - you can write a small server within your Node project and have that handle all routine browser requests as well as those particular to the web app concerned. But things like webpage changes are handled better by a web server, e.g. Nginx. So although you don't have to involve a web server with Node, it's often wiser to do so.

Comment: Is C++ a webserver? No, it's a programming language that you can use to write one. Same with node.js.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### [Web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server)

> Web server can refer to either the hardware (the computer) or the
>   software (the computer application) that helps to deliver content that
>   can be accessed through the Internet.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server)
>
> The primary function of a web server is to deliver web pages on the
>   request to clients. This means delivery of HTML documents and any
>   additional content that may be included by a document, such as images,
>   style sheets and scripts.

A web server is the basic to delivering requests/pagess to the clients/user on the internet

### [Web framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)

> A web application framework is a software framework that is designed
>   to support the development of dynamic websites, web applications and
>   web services. The framework aims to alleviate the overhead associated
>   with common activities performed in Web development. For example, many
>   frameworks provide libraries for database access, templating
>   frameworks and session management, and they often promote code reuse.

A web framework uses a webserver to deliver the requests to client, but it is not the web server.

### [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
>   building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
>   event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
>   efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run
>   across distributed devices.

But then again you can also create CLI apps so I think you should see it more as a platform to write javascript programs to run on your server(computer) using [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) instead of just in the browser as in the beginning. I think you could see it as `Javascript++` ??

You can also write web server with node.js as you can see on the front page of node.js. In the beginning Ryan said you could put [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) in front of node.js because of the stabilty of the project. The project was and still is pretty young. Nginx is a proven web server that will keep on running while node.js can crash. Then again a lot of user just use node.js for that.

Comment: Node.js is a JavaScript **runtime** built on **Google's V8 JavaScript engine**...

Comment: How can web servers(apache or nginx) be hardware?

Comment: I think that the main question is whether Node.js listens to the HTTP port by default? If so, it classifies it as a HTTP server as well.

Comment: We can say that square is a rectangle but not the other way around. are you saying that Nodejs is more than just a web server? or does it not represent a web server at all?

Comment: @shadow0359 A bit late, but for anyone else that reads this, the web server isn't just the software. It can also mean the physical hardware, the computer where the software is running

Comment: I think it can be confusing because when we refer to the doc https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/ , it says we can build web server using NodeJS. People incl. myself are confused if NodeJS contains web server capabilities that we can enable by just writing 10-15 lines of codes.

Answer (score 29):

I would say [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a [Runtime Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_system) or a Runtime Engine.

Probably the best definition I have found so far comes from an article by Rob Gravelle entitled ["An Intro to Node.js"](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/an-intro-to-node.js.html#fbid=JPNrbF6-LXB):

> Node.js is part runtime environment and part library for building network applications using server-side JavaScript. It uses Chrome's JavaScript runtime engine to execute JS code directly without the need for the browser sandbox.

Also the PCMAG.COM Encyclopedia provides the [following definition](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,1237,t=runtime+engine&i=56079,00.asp) of "runtime engine":

> Software that certain applications depend on to run in the computer. The runtime engine must be running in the computer in order for the application to execute. It provides common routines and functions that the applications require, and it typically converts the program, which is in an interim, intermediate language, into machine language.

Also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_system) entitled "Run-time system" declares:

> A run-time system (also called runtime system, runtime environment, or just runtime) implements the basic behavior of a computer language, whether the language is a compiled language, interpreted language, embedded domain-specific language, or is invoked via an API as is pthreads.
>
> ... A run-time system may implement behavior of tasks such as drawing text on the screen or making an Internet connection. It also typically acts as an abstraction layer that hides the complexity or variations in the services offered by the operating system.

Well, are there any runtime environments (or even software platforms) like Node.js out there? I guess JRE is a good example of such an environment. Node.js and JRE - they have many in common. They all have (a kind of) virtual machine, a class library and a framework to implement many types of applications, including CLI ones.

So, getting back to your question, can we say that Node.js is a web server? Let's change "Node.js" for "JRE" and answer if JRE is a web server. The answer is no.

All that we can say is that Node.js is a runtime environment which one may use to implement a web server. Well, that's my opinion.

Comment: You ignore the purpose of having that runtime in the first place - as well as the uselessness of having it without all the modules [https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/] essential to making it do anything really useful.

Answer (score 28):

Saying node is a webserver is like saying javacript can only run inside a browser, you can say that but it can also do a lot of other things.

### NodeJS

1. [Javascript runtime enviroment(Chrome v8 engine) + Node
   Library/APIs]
2. Can create a web server, can also be described as a
   Application server

### Express

1. Web framework (uses nodejs's webserver to serve files)

### Nginx

1. Web server

In production most people use Nginx in front of node server as a proxy server to serve static files and other various elements like caching, routing etc.

Comment: plus one for mentioning that NodeJS can be used for both a webserver and an Application server, and for mentioning the Express.

Answer (score 18):

I would classify node.js as a server framework, with packages available that can make use of it as an HTTP server, or a WebSocket server, or your own custom protocol, etc.

The reason you might put nginx in front of your node.js server is for HTTP load balancing and reverse proxying across several machines running your server application.

Comment: Yes. A web framework helps you write a web application, which uses HTML and JavaScript for the UI, and communicates over HTTP. Examples of a web framework would be Express for node.js, or Django for Python.

Comment: The best answer of all attempts. +1.

Comment: i guess sticking ngnix would not be appropriaite solution , we can use hs proxy for load balncing solution

Comment: @cmv sorry Im late to the convo!!! Do you have to put nginx in front of node to but a Load Balancer on it though? Can I just put the load balancer in front of the EC2 instance and be done with it to let it funnel uin straigt through to the node and express endpoints?

Answer (score 13):

How I feel your pain !

Like many, I found it hard to get to the essence of Node.js because most people only write/talk about the part of Node that they find useful - and the part they find interesting is usually a secondary benefit of Node rather than its primary purpose. I must say that I think it's mad for people to say that Node is just a JavaScript runtime. Node's use of JavaScript - and its selection of the V8 runtime - are simply *means to an end*, the best tools for the problem that Node's developers wanted to solve.

Node's primary purpose was to make the management of user events in a web app more efficient. So Node is *overwhelmingly* used on the back end of a web app. Event management demands that something is listening at the server machine for these user events. So a http server must be set up to route each event to its appropriate handler script. Node provides a framework for quickly setting up a server to listen on a dedicated port for user requests. Node uses JavaScript for event handling *because JavaScript allows functions to be called as objects*. This allows the task to be executed immediately after an asynchronous request (e.g. to a file system, database or network) to be wrapped in a function and referenced as a parameter of the asynchronous request function call.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const conn = mysql.createConnection(
{
    host: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    database: "doa_statsbase",
    user: "uoalabama_doas",
    password: "*************"
});
. . . 
. . . 
const analyse_bigwheat_farmers = (err, result, fields) =>
{
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    return data_object;
}
. . . 
. . .
let query = "SELECT * FROM us_farmers WHERE acreage > '1000' AND crop='wheat'"; 

mysql.query(query, (err, result, fields) =>
{
   analyse_bigwheat_farmers(err, result, fields);
}
. . . 
. . . 
. . .
```

Not many other languages treat functions as objects and those that do may not have an interpreter as efficient as Google's V8 runtime. Most web developers already know JavaScript so there's no additional language learning with Node. What's more, having callback functions *allows all user tasks  to be put on a single thread* without having explicit blocking applied to tasks demanding access to the database or file system. And this is what leads to the superior executional efficiency of Node under heavy concurrent use - the primary purpose for its development.

Today, most Node web applications use callbacks sparingly as JavaScript ES6 introduced the *Promise* construct in 2015 to handle asynchronous calls more easily and readably.

To help Node users quickly write back end code, Node's developers also organized both a built-in JS library for routine tasks (e.g. matters related to HTTP requests, string (de)coding, streams etc) and the NPM (Node Package Manager) repositary: this is an open source, user-maintained set of script packages for various standard and custom functions. All Node projects allow importation of NPM packages into a project via the established ***npm install***  command.

User requests handled via Node will be things needed by the web app like authentication, database querying, content management system (ApostropheCMS, Strapi CMS) updates, etc. All these will be sent to the Node port. (Where analysis of data got from a database is takes a lot of CPU time, this type of process is best put on a separate thread so it doesn't slow simpler user requests.) Other types of user request, e.g. to load another webpage, download CSS/JS/image files, etc, will continue to be sent by the browser to the default ports (typically ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) on the server machine where the web server program (Apache, NGinx, etc) will handle them in the mode of a traditional website.

*[A side note here on request streaming to the server. Since most server machines' firewalls only allow the default ports 80/443 open, it is not usually allowed to **directly** send a Node.js request with another port in the URL, e.g. https://mynodeapp.com:3001/fetch-members. If one did, the server machine's firewall would simply ignore it as it directly references an illegal port.
Instead one could apply a URL to the request that has no explicit port number but which contains a virtual folder name that identifies the Node.js app, e.g.  https://mynodeapp.com/mynodeapp/fetch-members.  Then append some server directive code on the .htaccess file like:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mynodeapp/(.*) https://localhost:3001/$1 [P]
```

*Node.js requests given URLs in this way will thus find their way to the Node.js server for that web app via the nominated ports for the Node application, i.e. 3001 in the example here.]*

So, in practice, Node is principally a framework for rapid server-creation and event-handling but one that replaces only some of the functions of the web server program.

Other non-backend uses of Node simply exploit one or other of its features, e.g. the JavaScript V8 engine. For example, the frontend build tools **Grunt** and **Gulp** use a frontend Node.js app to process a build script that can be coded to convert SASS to CSS, minify CSS/JS files, optimize image size or image loading, generate page-state HTML files for refreshing page-states in a single page application site, etc. But this sort of work is really just a by-product use of Node and not its principal use which is for making efficient backend processes for modern web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Web server is something that serves its clients through internet over protocols and Web Framework is something like which we call as compiler. It consists of all the required libraries, syntax rules, etc.

And node.js is a framework!!

Comment: But doesn't Node include modules (e.g. http) designed to enable one to quickly code their own server ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the terminology of "web server" or "web application server" is dominated by the JEE world, and products, that are not as modularized as today's Javascript world of frameworks, which in turn can be combined more or less freely.

I see no reason why a technology, that can serve complex applications over the web, should **not** be called a web server, or web application server!

If you combine, let's say [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide) as a frontend, with [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com/) as a backend - you'll have a backend serving a REST API and a server-side rendered UI!

Of course, you could (mis)use that to serve static content - then I'd call it a web server, or you could use it to make and serve a full application - then I'd call it a web application server.

It's the combined features or qualities that sum up to serve a purpose - right? - Features like stability, scalability and such are IMHO something that will be added to those technologies, over time. For now, they're pretty new still.

Answer (score 0):

No it's a runtime environment... so it is not a web server yet it does not need one to run. So probably this is why it could be confusing. It can run standalone without needing any webserver because it is a runtime itself but again it is not a webserver.

Comment: I think this answer - though technically true - is too brief and not informative to a newbee.

Comment: your answer implies that runtimes can just perform the functionality of a webserver, which isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Node.js for the first time to create a Discord bot. My thought was "Wow, Node.js is a server? I thought it was a JS library!" Or perhaps I could have thought about it as a framework.

Is it a web server? No but you can make one with it.
Is it a server? As in the software that receives queries and serves the result? Yes.

In my case, I have issued the command:
`node index.js`

And now Node.js is waiting for requests to respond to (via my bot). It's a server, but it isn't serving web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Although Nodejs is treated as a pretty cool, lightweight runtime environment and consists an awesome package manager called npm in node ecosystem. You can spin up a REST API, web application server using express framework which serves to a dedicated port. And it primarily required no web server on top of it.
whereas web server's main agenda is to serve as layer 7 loadbalancer and proxy server. According to Industry Standard most commonly used web server is nginx due to reliability. Although you can configure a http proxy server using node libraries and express framework.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).