# Does NodeJs uses "root directory"?

Tags: node.js, conventions, document-root

Does NodeJs uses  "root directory"? like apache?

I know that you can extend or change the defaults also in apache and other servers, but - are tere any conventions with nodeJS?

### edit

I'm not asking where it is or how to get it, what i ask is: is there any default root directory? like htdocs..

Comment: in nodejs you have `process.cwd()` for the current working directory, also variable `__dirname` points to the js executed

Comment: but please note, unlike apache, nodejs itself is not a webserver.

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks. (i've edited the question).
as to the second comment - can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462356/can-we-say-node-js-is-a-web-server#answer-9484970