# how does node js, when used as a server, can be defined in the context of a web server/ application server?

Tags: node.js, express, webserver, application-server, web-container

I try to understand the architecture nodejs, when using it as a server trough framework such as express. 
I know all these concepts of web server, application server, and a web container but I don't
think that I fully grasped where does nodejs as a server it's to all of this.

Comment: Node.js is the runtime, like the JVM in Java or the interpreter in Python. It's what implements the JavaScript language, namely what executes the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we say node.js is a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462356/can-we-say-node-js-is-a-web-server)

Comment: no, sorry:) because I know that node.js is a runtime that also has an HTTP module that express is using in order to generate a server- and that's my question - this 'server' that is running on node- in the context of what is running? is it an application server? webserver? none of it?